# Проблема с реляционным запросом в Yii2

Tags: pdo, yii2, yii, php, sql

Здравствуйте.

Поступила задача вывести голосование и все варианты ответов. Я пытаюсь сделать такой запрос:

```
$model = app\models\Reports::find()->where(['id'=>$model->id])->joinWith('reportData')->one();
```

Код реляционного запроса:

```
public function getReportData(){
    return $this->hasMany(ReportsData::className(), ['report_id'=>'id'])->where(['can_take'=>1]);
}
```

Однако когда выполняется запрос №1($model = ...), получаю ошибку вида:

```
Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `tb_reports`.* FROM `tb_reports` LEFT JOIN `tb_reports_data` ON `tb_reports`.`id` = `tb_reports_data`.`report_id` WHERE (`id`=1) AND (`can_take`=1)

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1052
    [2] => Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
)

↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

in /var/www/yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 819
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать и в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Попробовал, тоже самое. Всё работает, если убрать joinWith('reportData') :(

Comment: Исправил ответ, попробуйте написать:

    joinWith('report_data')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуй

```
$model = app\models\Reports::find()->where(['tb_reports.id'=>$model->id])->joinWith('reportData')->one();
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можете подсказать, что за магия?

Comment: Магия в том, что надо учить построение запросов. ))))))))

Answer (score 1):

А как у вас так получается, что `"$model ="`, а внутри атрибут `"$model->id"`? Разберитесь, что именно у вас в переменной `$model`. А вообще, чтобы упростить выражение, попробуйте сделать так:

```
$model = Reports::findByPk($other_model->id)->joinWith('report_data')->one();
```

**UPD.** Исправил  `joinWith('reportData')` на `joinWith('report_data')`.

Comment: У меня нету report_data, у меня именно reportData(в первом посте код)

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE (`id`=1) AND (`can_take`=1)

Укажите имена таблиц, откуда берутся эти столбцы, в частности id. Возможно, так:

```
 WHERE (`tb_reports`.`id`=1) AND (`can_take`=1)
```